# PHP include link not working when fetching edit ID

Tags: php, mysql, url, include, crud

first time posting here, but need help as I am quite new to PHP, and I've searched but couldn't find a similar question.

My index file has this php include:

```
include($_GET['underside']);
```

On one of my other pages (opret.php) I've created a CRUD and everything works. However when I try to fetch the data from a given ID, in to my inputs, the link won't work with the include.

The link is as following:

```
<a href="opret.php?rediger=<?php echo $row['TilbudId']; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Rediger</a>
```

Which ends up being this in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/StampIT/index.php?underside=opret.php?rediger=7
```

I know this seems a bit far out, but I don't know if theres a way around it. I am getting these errors:

> Warning: include(opret.php?rediger=7): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp64\www\StampIT\index.php on line 56

And

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'opret.php?rediger=7' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp64\www\StampIT\index.php on line 56

I can make it work if I just forget about includes and make separate pages for everything, however I would really like to avoid that.

I hope someone can help, and that it was somewhat understandable. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is not specific to PHP. Reading files from your hard disk is different from reading web sites. Your code is mixing both things.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. I think running `include` with unfiltered input are a potential security hole. You should consider a different strategy. (for example, see comment: https://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#120069 )

Answer (score 1):

`http://localhost:8080/StampIT/index.php?underside=opret.php?rediger=7`

You have to seperate GET parameters with a & sign. It has to be

`http://localhost:8080/StampIT/index.php?underside=opret.php&rediger=7`

Besides: The include looks like a potential file inclusion vulnerability. An attacker could manipulate that parameter and include a file (or probably even remote script) that is not supposed to be processed by your site. For example index.php?underside=/etc/passwd

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. I am not too concerned about the file inclusion vulnerability, as it's for a school project, and we haven't been taught about security yet, so I wouldn't know what to change :-)